# (Combinatorics) Positioning numbered books between other books

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have encountered a problem for which I don't have an idea how to solve. 
In how many ways can 40 books be positioned on a shelf, 10 of which are numbered books from 1 to 10 (they can, but don't have to be next to eachother), so that the numbered books are always positioned in ascending order?

I thought of positioning the numbered books first and that could probably be done in 1 way, but I am not sure of that because we have 40 open slots. For the first book each of those 40 slots can be chosen and for the second book we only have that many slots that are on the right of the first one.

How can I approach this in the right way? Any thought is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have 40 slots. There are ${40\choose10}$ ways of selecting 10 of them, and just one way of placing the numbered books into the selected slots. Presumably order matters for the remaining 30 books, so there are then $30!$ ways of placing them in the 30 remaining slots. Alternatively, if they are regarded as indistinguishable, there is just one way.